# The apply function returns "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r

I have a data frame called 'bank' like below, it has around 40K rows

```
  age  job      salary marital education targeted default balance housing loan contact day month
  58 management 100000 married  tertiary      yes      no    2143     yes   no unknown   5   may

  duration campaign pdays previous poutcome response
       261        1    -1        0  unknown       no
```

I created the following function that checks some conditions and then returns a value that gets added as a new value under a new column called 'new'.

```
decide <- function(x){
  if(x$marital=='married' & x$salary > 60000 & x$housing=='yes'){
    return('yes') 
  }else if(x$marital=='single' & x$salary > 40000 & x$education=='tertiary'){
    return('yes') 
  }else{
    return('no') 
  }
}
```

Then I would use the below loop to run over all the rows and derive the new value

```
for(i in 1:nrow(bank)){
  person<-bank[i,]
  bank[i,'new']<-decide(person)
}
```

This satisfies my requirement.

However when I try to use an apply function instead of a for loop like below,

```
bank$new1<-sapply(bank,decide)
```

it returns the below error

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What is the issue with the apply function I wrote, can I ask you to write the correct apply function that works like the for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
decide <- function(x){
  if(x["cyl"]==6 & x["disp"] > 150){
    return('yes') 
  }else if(x["cyl"] == 8 & x["disp"] > 200){
    return('yes') 
  }else{
    return('no') 
  }
}

apply(mtcars, 1, decide)
```

Slightly more elegant and efficient:

```
with(mtcars, ifelse(cyl == 6 & disp > 150, "yes", ifelse(cyl==8 & disp > 200, "no", "no")))
```

Here, `ifelse` works on vectors, which means you do not have to loop through the entire dataframe.

To understand your error, note that the `apply`-function would pass a vector to the function, and vectors are not accessed with $. See:

```
vec <- c("a"=1, "b"=2)
vec
# a b 
# 1 2 
vec$a
# Error in vec$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
vec["a"]
# a 
# 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can use `dplyr::case_when` in such situations where there are multiple conditions will decide value of `new` column. The logic will look  simpler and neat as:

```
library(dplyr)

bank %>% mutate(new = case_when(
    marital=='married' & salary > 60000 & housing=='yes' ~ 'yes', 
    marital=='single' & salary > 40000 & education=='tertiary' ~ 'yes',
    TRUE                      ~ 'no'
       ))
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but you answered  1 min faster :)

Comment: Sorry mate. Better luck next time.